# other meaning of the idiom "go hungry"

Tags: word-meaning

> Then,  as  his  final  gift  to  his  students,  the  professor  gave  them  a  piece  of  advice. "Remember,"  he  said  to them,  "the  four  of  you  may  be  proficient,  each in  your  own  subject,  but  if  you don't  have  the  sense  to  act  suitably  to  the  time  and  circumstance  of  a  situation,  you  may  have  to  go hungry."

This sentence is from a folk -tale.I want to know whether we can use the meaning "go hungry" for referring to "a situation that causes problems",besides its original meaning "not having enough food to eat".

Comment: I would say no, not exactly. If you want a phrase to mean "a situation that causes problems," I would say, "...you may be in hot water." This is a "situation that is problematic," though perhaps not causing problems in and of itself.

Comment: Meanwhile, "you may have to go hungry" in itself is an idiomatic expression and does not only mean "not having enough food to eat." Of course, it borrows its idiomatic meaning from its literal one: one would go hungry without having enough food to eat, but there is also a little bit of the understanding that something had occurred (or not occurred) for you to be in this status of "being hungry."

Comment: It is possible to use language in a more metaphorical or extended way, but you would have to make it clear.  In general, if I read **go hungry**, I am going to think first of literally going without food, and secondarily of being poor and needy.  But *go hungry* doesn't mean "a situation that causes problems".

Comment: http://youthandeducationinmyanmar.blogspot.com/2017/09/too-much-knowledge-maketh-fools.html

Answer (score 1):

In this story, "to go hungry" is understood by the students to mean simply "to go hungry", it's not an idiom with any other understood meaning.

> Not quite comprehending what the great teacher meant, they looked at one another, but said nothing, and after paying their respects to their professor, set forth on their journey home.

The story itself is a fable, and means that your day-to-day needs must be provided for not by advanced knowledge but by common sense, which is the minimum set of sense, knowledge and skills everyone is expected to have.

- Too much knowledge maketh fools: http://youthandeducationinmyanmar.blogspot.com/2017/09/too-much-knowledge-maketh-fools.html